# Porting Android on i.mx53

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I am trying to port Android on i.mx53 board. I have prepared my SD card and downloaded all the related images on it (u-boot.bin /uImage/uramdisk, system.img , recovery.img) . After this I am stuck , I don't know how to connect my board with my ubuntu pc , and how to launch u-boot on my device so that I can see the u-boot console .
Thanks !!

Comment: [i.MX53](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I.MX#i.MX53_family) is actually a [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip). Which exactly **board** you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly it's supposed to be done on your particular board, but the whole procedure is quite common for all ARM-based devices with Android. So I'm gonna describe some generalized working process.

### Connection between your board and PC

Usually you need to connect your board (target) and PC (host) with 2 USB cables:

1. [OTG USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) cable (for [flashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware#Flashing) (uploading) firmware to your device).

   For actual flashing you need to use [fastboot](http://elinux.org/Android_Fastboot) tool on PC. Your device should be in fastboot mode (special mode of u-boot, you can reach it by issuing `fastboot` command in u-boot shell).
2. USB cable for [serial console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_console) (sometimes called "Terminal"). Some boards don't have integrated [RS-232 to USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTDI) chip; in that case you need to use external [RS-232 to USB converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_adapter).

   You should use some serial communication program on your PC (e.g. [minicom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom)) to communicate with your device.

### Booting device from SD card

If your board doesn't have any preloaded software on it (particularly bootloader, which is u-boot in your case), you can only boot from SD card. It's because you need u-boot running in [fastboot](http://elinux.org/Android_Fastboot) mode on your device to flash any images via OTG USB (using fastboot tool on PC). Exception is for devices that have [ROM code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#Other_kinds_of_boot_sequences) able to communicate with some special PC tool, so you can upload images to [eMMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard#eMMC) (or any other storage used on your device) with no need in u-boot.

Below are steps need to be done in order to boot from SD card.

1. SD card should be prepared properly. An actual procedure is SoC-specific and usually can be found in [Technical Reference Manual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_guide) or some similar technical documentation for your SoC.

   For example here is SD card configuration for [OMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMAP)-based devices:

   - first partition should be FAT32
   - first partition should has [boot flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_flag)
   - first partition label is usually `boot`
   - first partition should have next files:

     - file called `MLO` (stands for "Memory Loader"), which is first-stage bootloader; it's usually **u-boot SPL** or **x-loader**
     - `u-boot.img` (second-stage bootloader)
     - `uImage` (Linux kernel image in u-boot format)
     - device tree file (`*.dtb`) in case your kernel uses [device tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_tree)
     - [u-boot environment](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootEnvVariables) file
   - second partition should be ext4 FS
   - second partition should contain Android [rootfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory) files (or any other rootfs, like [BusyBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) rootfs)

   If you just need to run u-boot from SD and go to fastboot mode, you only need first partition with `MLO` and `u-boot.img` files on it.
2. Select SD card as boot source on your board. It's usually can be done switching some [DIP switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIP_switch) often called as **boot mode** or **SYSBOOT**. It will tell your SoC to boot from selected device (SD card in your case) via so called [eFUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFUSE)s. Refer to your board documentation for details.

After that just perform reset and you will see u-boot running. Press "Enter" in your serial console (minicom) to enter u-boot shell. In u-boot shell execute `fastboot` command. Once your device in fastboot mode, you can flash all your images to eMMC (or any other storage your board uses), using `fastboot` tool on your PC. Usually you have `fastboot.sh` script in your Android build, which can flash all the images to the device for you.